# How to concatenate a set of paths and a set of the reflected paths about a certain axis in a single \pscustom?

Tags: pstricks

I want to draw a symmetric object made of a large number of points. To make the code cleaner, I want to use reflection technique. It means I just specify points on one side of the symmetrical axis, the points on the other side will be obtained by reflecting the specified points.

Finally I want to concatenate those parts in `\pscustom` and do other  operations such as filling or stroking.

The following code snippet is just a simple example that has been trimmed off for the sake of simplicity, but it failed to produce the required symmetric object.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=10pt\relax

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \def\left{\psline(0,2)(2,0)(0,-2)}%
    \pscustom[
        fillstyle=solid,
        fillcolor=yellow,
        linecolor=red
    ]{
        \left
        \psscalebox{-1 1}{\left}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

How to concatenate a set of paths and a set of the reflected paths about a certain axis in a single `\pscustom`?

Note: I also want to get the corners on which the part and its reflected part meet properly glued as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,
          fillcolor=yellow,
          linecolor=red]{%
  \psline(0,2)(2,0)(0,-2)
  \code{ -1 1 scale }\moveto(0,2)
  \psline(0,2)(2,0)(0,-2)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I still don't understand why the top and bottom points look jagged. `\pscustom` should make the corners nice as usual. I give up!

Comment: for the top use `linejoin=1` the bottom is a problem, because the path is not really a closed one.

Comment: no, it is a very special case that you want to mirror a path and then filling it. It already works correct for a default path setting.